# How should I include in my static library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I'm creating a static library that I intend for other people to use. This static library utilizes the Windows header, and in many of the functions it uses Windows definitions, such as DWORD, PDWORD, LPVOID, etc. I want these to be somewhat strict as to *really* define the functions in my library, reducing misuse. However, if I include the Windows header inside the header files of my static library, then someone who includes my library will automatically have the Windows header also included, and I don't believe this is the correct way of going about this process as many of the libraries I typically include in my other projects also require that I include the correct header files. So how should I go about "requiring" that people who use my library also include the windows header, or at least have my library check to see if the windows header is already included? This applies to other headers too, just in general (i.e. if I had to include iostream, then I would want to check if the iostream header was already included).

Essentially, should my static library take precedence over all of the user's includes, or adapt depending on what the user had already included? If the user includes my library, is it better to have them simply include my library's header and nothing else, or is there some way to make it so the user includes what they need in addition to my library?

For some extra clarity:

```
#include "MyLibrary.h"
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    // Stuff
}
```

Or

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "MyLibrary.h"
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    // Stuff
}
```

Comment: If this is a Windows library, then including Windows header files is expected. Why would that be a problem? Wrangling `HWND` to `void*` is asking for trouble. I have no idea what "programming integrity" means here. If your library uses Windows types, then it must include that file, and anyone using your library must as well.

Comment: In a header file I try to use the least amount of includes as possible and avoid using headers that pull in many other headers. I do this to reduce compile time, since it already takes several minutes to build my software.

Comment: Right. But I'm going to ```#include <Windows.h>``` in my header file, which automatically includes the windows header for anyone who includes my header file, and instead I want them to include the windows header on their own in addition to my header, despite the fact that I also use the windows header. I want my library to check if the user is already including the Windows header, and provided they aren't, then I would include it, but use the Windows header if it's already included. Essentially, I don't want my library to take precedence over the user's includes.

Comment: Can't you just include the file that defines `HWND` and `DWORD` instead?

Comment: Well, I don't know how it is done in Windows, but shouldn't `Windows.h` itself provide the guard `#ifndef`

Comment: @drescherjm Does such a file exist for all other libraries in C++? The point of the question was to clarify whether or not my library should always take precedence or always check if the user has already done the dependency work for me.

Comment: I don't think there is a one size fits all solution.

Comment: If your program, independently of your library, uses windows.h you should include it. If only the library includes it it shouldn't be included in the program.
The program shouldn't have to worry about what headers are needed for your library to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter how many times you include `Windows.h`, it already encloses its content within a `#ifndef` - `#endif` construct. If it was included once, some macro is already defined and the code in the header will not be included again.

On the other hand, if your library is static, it does not rely anymore on any external code, all symbols coming from `Windows.h` are effectively private to the library and not seen by anything else.

**EDIT** : to clarify your last edit.

The public API should be in the .h of your library. If `Windows.h` is not part of the API you offer, you better put it in your .cc, so, second option. If, on the contrary, some definitions from `Windows.h` are used in the definition of your public API, include it in your .h.

Comment: If you want the API to be in terms of `DWORD`, etc., then I would say that those are part of the API.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and after reading again the question it seems that is what the OP wants... Let me edit.